# Eslint hook refactor useEffect

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, eslint

I create useEffect like that. I want useEffect listen useToken and when I login and set token it will fetch some data

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (userToken) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        fetchDataWishlistShow();
        fetchCart();
      }, 500);
    }
    fetchCategory();
  }, [userToken]);
```

But Eslint of hook automatic add some function to Effect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (userToken) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        fetchDataWishlistShow();
        fetchCart();
      }, 500);
    }
    fetchCategory();
  }, [fetchCart, fetchCategory, fetchDataWishlistShow, userToken]);
```

Why it do that. I think it wrong but anyone can explain for me?

Comment: [...]  passed to the hooks indicates the dependencies list. It means your hook function is dependent on those parameters. so if one of the dependencies get changed your hook will run again. To make sure your hook will run only for `userToken` you can wrap `fetchCart` and other functions using `React.useCallback`

Comment: Yes I understand your idea. I will use useCallback for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you installed "eslint-plugin-react-hooks" and enable it.

`useEffect`is designed the way that which ever you use in you `useEffect` you are recommended to add it it dependencies array list EXCEPT some things that React guarantee that they are not changed every each re-render such as: dispatch of useReducer, setState form `const [state, setState] = useState()` or functions or variables imported from other files.

You can turn off the rule but you **SHOULD NOT** do that because you did not solve the source of the problem. E.g

```
const [cartStatus, setCartState] = useState("all") // assume it can be "all", "pending"

const fetchCart = () =>{
   fetch(`endpoint/cart/${cardStatus}`)
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (userToken) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        fetchDataWishlistShow();
        fetchCart();
      }, 500);
    }
    fetchCategory();
    // This case you alway fetch all item in cart
  }, [userToken]);
```

To fix issue above you saying you saying, yeah we can just add `fetchCart` into dependency list, but it'll cause infinite re-render, you need to wrap `fetchCart` by useCallback or move `fetchCart` into `useEffect`. Because you call the function inside setTimeout, you might want to clean the `useEffect`

```
const [cartStatus, setCartState] = useState("all") // assume it can be "all", "pending"


useEffect(() => {
   const fetchCart = () =>{
     fetch(`endpoint/cart/${cardStatus}`)
   }
   let id = null
    if (userToken) {
      id = setTimeout(() => {
        fetchDataWishlistShow();
        fetchCart();
      }, 500);
    }
    fetchCategory();
    return () => clearTimeout(id);  
  }, [userToken]);
```

[This article is written by Dan Abramov](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#dont-lie-to-react-about-dependencies) is a good resource to look at and deep dive into how `useEffect` works and why you should follow the recommended way.

You might saying that "No no, I am only have api call when the component mounted, That's it". But when your project grown, and you components become complicated, it's hard to remember that, who's know that your requirements might be changed at some point in the future, why don't do it in proper way to give you more confident when refactor or update your components?